# ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
car['kms_driven']=car['kms_driven'].str.split('').str.get(0).str.replace(',','')
car['kms_driven'] = car[car['kms_driven'].str.isnumeric()]
```

I am getting error below, please assist.

```
                                 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-f79352726c60> in <module>
----> 1 car['kms_driven'] = car[car['kms_driven'].str.isnumeric()]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3012
   3013         # Do we have a (boolean) 1d indexer?
-> 3014         if com.is_bool_indexer(key):
   3015             return self._getitem_bool_array(key)
   3016

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py in is_bool_indexer(key)
    112                     # Don't raise on e.g. ["A", "B", np.nan], see
    113                     #  test_loc_getitem_list_of_labels_categoricalindex_with_na
--> 114                     raise ValueError(na_msg)
    115                 return False
    116             return True

ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values
```

Comment: that's what error says try `car[car['kms_driven'].str.isnumeric().fillna(False)]`